# Closed User Group doesn't redirect to given Login page

Tags: aem

I am giving a page a closed user group. However it always redirects to /content/geometrixx/en/toolbar/account/login.html NOT the login page i've given it. Has anyone experienced this? The cq:cugLoginPage in the jcr is set to the correct page. Cheers

Comment: Just in case: Your login page is not a child of the page that is protected with a CUG?

Comment: Could you please share the dialog configuration? Make sure you have selected some admitted group.

Comment: shed some more light mate as per the comments above

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is know AEM bug. And official workaround is to customize login page and depends on your situation make redirect to page that you need.

On the [helpx.adobe.com](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/HowToSetupCUG.html) you can find other know bugs and workarounds for them.

Note: there is an official `hotfix-11598` for AEM 6.2 which is fixing this issue.